# EML vs MAI mail format

Tags: file-format, eml, mailenable

I would like to allow variant end users to download a message file from my system "As Is" so they will be able to open in easily.

i don't want to use the Outlook .msg format because not all of the users have Microsoft Outlook. HTML is not good because i can not convert emails with attachments to HTML.

I investigated and found 2 common formats. EML and MAI.

Can you explain about each of them so i will be able to decide on the right format?

while testing, i took MAI file, renamed it to EML and i could successfully open if with programs supports EML files like Outlook so i am wondering, is it the same format but with different extension only?

I added the MailEnable tag because i understood that if i am taking EML file and rename it to MAI it should work. and i am wondering if its correct without no exceptions. Because as per my understanding, EML if more common so i may choose that format but i still want to be able to load the EML files to MailEnable inbox for searching and manage using the Web interface.

Answer (score 0):

EML isn't a format, it's just a file extension that is typically used for email messages in the MIME format.

I have no idea what MAI is, I've never heard of it and Google isn't turning anything up.

Since MIME is the only standard email format in existence, use that.